# Prove that $6^n+8^n$ is divisible by $7$ iff $n$ is odd

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, proof-writing

The question:

> Prove that $6^n+8^n$ is divisible by $7$ iff $n$ is odd.

Hence, prove $7 | 6^n + 8^n \iff n ~$ is odd

I realise that this is a proof by induction, and this is what I have so far:

\begin{align}
f(n) & = 6^n + 8^n \\
& = (2\cdot 3)^n + (2^3)^n \\
& = 2^n \cdot 3^n + 2^{3n} \\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\text{Assume} ~ f(k) & = 6^k + 8^k \\
& = 2^k \cdot 3^k + 2^{3k} \\
f(k+1) & = 2^{k+1} \cdot 3^{k+1} + 2^{3(k+1)} \\
\end{align}

Where do I go from here?

Comment: I nominated for reopening. This question is not quite a duplicate of the linked one. In particular, there is a nice modular arithmetic argument available here which doesn't work in general.

Comment: Well, this is interesting. I already knew the answer to this question - I just wanted to try the Q&A answer style. I made sure that this was not a duplicate, and something people could learn from. If you feel the question was wrongly closed, please vote to reopen it, as my intentions are for the good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$6\equiv1\pmod7, ~8\equiv-1\pmod7$, hence $$6^n+8^n\equiv1^n+(-1)^n\pmod7$$ $1^n+(-1)^n=0~\iff~n$ is odd.

Answer (score 1):

This is my first attempt at answering my own question. I realise the question is of a low quality, but I'm focusing on the question-and-answer aspect.

There are a few issues with the OP's attempt. Firstly, the base step was skipped. Secondly, and crucially, $f(k+1)$ is no longer odd, so it cannot be used in the inductive step.

---

**Problem:** Prove that $6^n+8^n$ is divisible by $7$ iff $n$ is odd.

**Solution:** Let $f(n)$ denote the statement
\begin{align}
f(n) & = 6^n + 8^n \\
\end{align}

**Base Step ($n=1$):** 
\begin{align}
f(1) & = 6^1+8^1 \\
& = 6+8 \\
& = 14 \\
\end{align}
$7 | 14 \implies f(1)$ holds.

**Inductive Step $f(k) \to f(k+2)$:** Fix some $k$, where $k$ is odd. Assume that

$$f(k) = 6^k + 8^k$$

holds true. To be proved is that

$$f(k+2) = 6^{k+2} + 8^{k+2}$$

follows. Beginning with the left-hand side of $f(k+2)$,

\begin{align}
6^{k+2} + 8^{k+2} & = 6^k \cdot6^2 + 8^k \cdot 8^2 \\
& = 6^k \cdot 36 + 8^k \cdot 64 \\
& = 6^k + 6^k \cdot 35 + 8^k + 8^k \cdot63 \\
& = 6^k + 8^k + 6^k \cdot 35 + 8^k \cdot63 \\
& = f(k) + 7(6^k\cdot5+8^k \cdot9)
\end{align}
by the inductive assumption, $7 | f(k)$. Clearly, $7 | (6^k\cdot5+8^k \cdot9)$, thereby showing $f(k+2)$ is true, completing the inductive step.

**Conclusion:** By mathematical induction, it is proved that $6^n+8^n$ is divisible by $7$ iff $n$ is odd. $\Box$

Comment: Good answer. :)

Comment: I think this only proves one direction of the iff statement (though a simple mod 7 argument serves to quickly show the other direction (..actually mod 7 gives both directions very quickly))

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt: It depends on the OP's level,  I think. What if the OP doesn't know modular arithmetic yet? But you're right that he has proved only one direction and I didn't notice it was an iff statement.

Answer (score 0):

Because $$6^n+8^n=(6+8)(6^{n-1}-6^{n-2}\cdot8+...-6\cdot8^{n-2}+8^{n-1}).$$